# What Setting In Cura Determines The Value Of "G1 E-{switch_extruder_retraction_amount}" At The Beginning Of A Print?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code, slicing

I am trying to print the [Chep calibration cube](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3189377/files) sliced in Cura on my new Sovol SV04 Dual Extrusion printer. When I print the model the extruder prints the wipe line on the left of the bed, moves to the centre of the bed to begin the print and does a huge retraction (enough that it's almost the amount needed to change filaments), enough so that there is no filament in the nozzle and nothing comes out, I had to manually feed the filament back down in order to get it printing again.

The beginning of the G-code that Cura produces is as follows:

```
;FLAVOR:Marlin
;TIME:2593
;Filament used: 1.41417m
;Layer height: 0.1
;MINX:133.2
;MINY:133.2
;MINZ:0.2
;MAXX:168.8
;MAXY:168.8
;MAXZ:21
;Generated with Cura_SteamEngine 4.12.1
M82 ;absolute extrusion mode
;Single 01 start
M140 S60.0;
M104 T0 S210.0;
M280 P0 S160;
G4 P100;
G28;
T0
M190 S60.0;
M109 T0 S210.0;
G92 E0;
G1 X10.1 Y20 Z0.28 F5000.0;
G1 X10.1 Y200.0 Z0.28 F1500.0 E15;
G1 X10.4 Y200.0 Z0.28 F5000.0;
G1 X10.4 Y20 Z0.28 F1500.0 E30;
G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000;
G92 E0
G92 E0
G1 Z{retraction_hop_height_after_extruder_switch} F12000
G1 E-16
G92 E0
G92 E0
G1 F2400 E-3
;LAYER_COUNT:199
;LAYER:0
```

The problem seems to be caused by the line `G1 E-16` which I think comes from the extruder start G-code, however, I cannot seem to find what causes the retraction to be so large. The Start G-code for my printer is:

```
;Single 01 start
M140 S{material_bed_temperature};
M104 T0 S{material_print_temperature};
M280 P0 S160;
G4 P100;
G28;
T0
M190 S{material_bed_temperature};
M109 T0 S{material_print_temperature};
G92 E0;
G1 X10.1 Y20 Z0.28 F5000.0;
G1 X10.1 Y200.0 Z0.28 F1500.0 E15;
G1 X10.4 Y200.0 Z0.28 F5000.0;
G1 X10.4 Y20 Z0.28 F1500.0 E30;
G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000;
```

And the Start Gcode for the extruder is :

```
G92 E0
G1 Z{retraction_hop_height_after_extruder_switch} F12000
G1 E-{switch_extruder_retraction_amount}
G92 E0
```

All of the settings that I have for the printer in Cura are copied over directly from Sovol's own version of Cura as I wanted to try and use one programme for all of my printers. When I slice the model in the Sovol Cura it does not seem to produce the same problem with the G-code for the model as follows:

```
;FLAVOR:Marlin
;TIME:2394
;Filament used: 1.43625m
;Layer height: 0.15
;MINX:136.5
;MINY:136.5
;MINZ:0.2
;MAXX:165.5
;MAXY:165.5
;MAXZ:20.3
;Generated with Sovol Slicer 1.3.0
M82 ;absolute extrusion mode
;Single 01 start
M140 S60;
M104 T0 S190;
M280 P0 S160;
G4 P100;
G28;
T0
M190 S60;
M109 T0 S190;
G92 E0;
G1 X10.1 Y20 Z0.28 F5000.0;
G1 X10.1 Y200.0 Z0.28 F1500.0 E15;
G1 X10.4 Y200.0 Z0.28 F5000.0;
G1 X10.4 Y20 Z0.28 F1500.0 E30;
G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000;
G92 E0
G92 E0
G1 Z{retraction_hop_height_after_extruder_switch} F12000
G1 E-3
G92 E0
G92 E0
G1 F2100 E-3
;LAYER_COUNT:133
;LAYER:0
```

The `G1` command is set to `-3` instead of `-16` and I cannot determine why.

Any help that you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `-16` is an option in Cura, please filter on `switch`, to make it visible:

[image: Cura print settings, search for "switch"]

The search for the "switch" option shows a default value of `16` for the `Nozzle Switch Retraction Distance`.

---

*Your interpreted G-code contains the line `G1 Z{retraction_hop_height_after_extruder_switch} F12000` which is not expanded/translated. This is defined in your extruder change start script. Please check if the `Z Hop After Extruder Switch` is enabled.*

Comment: The Dual Extrusion options are not available due to the way the printer is set up, as copied from the Sovol Cura build, single extruder printing on the dual extruder is set up as its own printer called "Sovol SV04 Single-Mode 01" (the 01 designating the left extruder 02 the right), with only one extruder added, with dual, mirror and copy each having its own individual printer profile.